# Name of a comic about a young tyrannosaurus

Tags: story-identification, comics, dinosaurs

When I was young (maybe 25-30 years ago!) I read a comic book about a T-rex that was the last survivor of his nest. The story started off with his mother and the other young being killed by a larger T-rex and the survivor ended up with scars across his face. The rest of the story followed his survival as a lone young T-rex growing up and eventually challenging the attacking older T-rex.
The dinosaurs didn't speak, the story was driven through the images and narration text.

I am keen to track down the comic to read it again for nostalgia, but have been unable to identify it. Anyone able to help out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*[Bloodfang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloodfang)*, published in British comic *Eagle*, issues 116–127 and 129–158 (1983–84).

[image: Bloodfang with scars]

> The first series (12 episodes, 38 pages) begins with Bloodfang hatching from his egg, 100 million years ago. He promptly kills his siblings, and is raised by his mother, Karka, until she is killed in a fight with the tyrannosaur pack leader, Blackheart, who happens to be Bloodfang's father. During the fight Bloodfang is wounded in the face by Blackheart, leaving him with permanent scars. Bloodfang flees, and becomes an outcast from the pack.
>
> Forced to fend for himself, the young tyrannosaur initially struggles to survive, and nearly starves. His first meal without his mother's assistance consists of carrion. However, when other dinosaurs (four sauroctoni) try to steal his meal from him, he cunningly bides his time until they have gorged themselves, and then attacks them when, sleepy and bloated, they are vulnerable, killing two and driving the others away. Over the next four years he grows to become six metres tall and weigh ten tonnes, by which time he has learned to be a ferocious fighter, stronger than most adults of his species.
>
> Bloodfang returns to his pack during mating season, and kills a rival male tyrannosaur to steal his harem of females. Bloodfang quickly establishes his status as one of the strongest of the pack, but backs down when challenged by Blackheart, who is still the leader.
>
> Eventually, during a final reckoning, Bloodfang kills Blackheart and usurps him as leader of the pack, while the rest of the pack feast on Blackheart's corpse.

The second series apparently involves Bloodfang dealing with hunters from the 22nd century.

Found by searching for *comic young "tyrannosaurus rex" scars -"jurassic park"*

Comment: Wow. Really wish this was available as a collection somewhere!

Comment: @Marisa: Closest I've found is https://comicvine.gamespot.com/best-of-eagle-monthly-bloodfang/4000-323228/

Comment: Fuzzy, you are a legend!

Comment: @beldin0: Just lucky at finding the right search keywords.